# Inserting row between different cell values

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I am attempting to write from a DataTable to Excel file and I want to insert a blank row in between each 'WO Base ID' I am not sure how to approach this. I am using C# with .NET, I am using the package EPPlus, I understand how to add a new row and all that with EPPlus but I cannot figure out how to split the 'WO Base IDs" up. Any help is appreciated.

**Original Output**

```
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|    Part #     | Close Date | WO Base ID | WO Sub ID | Resource ID | Desired Qty |
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| F-COM-95650-1 | 12-04-2001 | WO05837    |         0 | KITTING     |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 12-04-2001 | WO05837    |         0 | PACKAGING   |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 03-20-2002 | WO06008    |         0 | KITTING     |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 03-20-2002 | WO06008    |         0 | PACKAGING   |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 05-01-2002 | WO06231    |         0 | KITTING     |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 05-01-2002 | WO06231    |         0 | PACKAGING   |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 11-07-2002 | WO06994    |         0 | KITTING     |         250 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 11-07-2002 | WO06994    |         0 | PACKAGING   |         250 |
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|    Part #     | Close Date | WO Base ID | WO Sub ID | Resource ID | Desired Qty |
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| F-COM-95650-1 | 12-04-2001 | WO05837    |         0 | KITTING     |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 12-04-2001 | WO05837    |         0 | PACKAGING   |          50 |

| F-COM-95650-1 | 03-20-2002 | WO06008    |         0 | KITTING     |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 03-20-2002 | WO06008    |         0 | PACKAGING   |          50 |

| F-COM-95650-1 | 05-01-2002 | WO06231    |         0 | KITTING     |          50 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 05-01-2002 | WO06231    |         0 | PACKAGING   |          50 |

| F-COM-95650-1 | 11-07-2002 | WO06994    |         0 | KITTING     |         250 |
| F-COM-95650-1 | 11-07-2002 | WO06994    |         0 | PACKAGING   |         250 |
+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to foreach your rows and hold track of the wo base id. When it changes compared to the previous row add an empty row?

Comment: You could loop through your table using a "break" control variable, that you initialize to the value of WO Base ID of the first DataRow.    
Then you start your loop (Foreach DataRow dr in  DataTable.Row)
if the value of the field is not equal to the value of the control value you
  1. insert a blank line
  2. set the value of the control variable to the value of the field of the current row

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, that helped me solve the problem!